# Updating Dell Vostro 3700 (Nvidia GeForce GT330M) display driver?

Tags: video, drivers, nvidia-geforce, dell-vostro

I've bought this laptop ***"Dell Vostro 3700"***, having inside an Intel integrated graphic card and an **Nvidia GeForce GT330M**.

Depending on energy saving mode it switches between the two video cards.

When I try to update the video driver (*now version 189.99 on Windows 7 64-bit*) with that found on Nvidia site an error message say that it cannot find compatible graphic hardware.

Dell doesn't provide a newer driver version.

Has anyone solved the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Intel integrated card is disabled in BIOS, as I assume you dont want to use it.  In Internet Exporer, go to Nvidia.com and go to the drivers page and manually download (or use the automated detection) to download the latest Nvidia driver.

Comment: Perhaps (also if i update BIOS) i can not disable the integrated graphics.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically forced to depend on Dell (or whomever the manufacturer is) for those mobile versions of the nVidia cards, especially if they are the Optimus hybrid type setups with the Intel video.   See similar requests from nVidia's forums, [Here](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=162180) and [Here](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=192477).

With a little elbow grease, you can try out [laptopvideo2go.com's driver 'scanner'](http://laptopvideo2go.com/drivers) to see if they have a modified nVidia driver that will work for you.  Or you can try some of the listed 'generic' modification versions that work with many models.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: [How to upgrade latest Nvidia driver for Dell Vostro 3700](http://ismailsaleh.net/2011/12/25/how-to-upgrade-latest-nvidia-driver-for-dell-vostro-3700/)

> - Uninstall NVidia Driver
> - Run Nasty File Remover (Please download from reputable website)
> - Download Intel HD driver from Intel web
> - Download NVidia Latest Driver from NVidia Web
> - Install Intel HD driver first.
> - It might not work, so after restart you need to go to Device Manager -> Display Adapter -> 1st VGA device, do Update Driver and browse for Intel HD driver you just download
> - After restart again, you will see you get back your normal resolution (1600 x 900). First step successful! Congrats! Clap! Clap!
>     Clap!
> - Now go to Device Manager again. Go for the only VGA device (another one is Intel HD, which we install driver already) -> Right Click,
>     Properties -> Details ->Select “Hardware ID”
> - You need to copy the Hardware ID. I recommend to copy it to Notepad.
> - Run Nvidia Installer
> - When it says No Hardware Detected, just cancel it.
> - Browse to where you extract the Nvidia Driver.
> - Find the file name “nvam.inf”
> - Edit this file in Notepad (I use notepad++)
> - You need to find this line -> NVIDIA_DEV.0A35.06 = “NVIDIA GeForce GT 325M     ”  (yes including the space and “)
> - Press Enter. Paste this -> NVIDIA_DEV.0A29.01 = “NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M” (yes including the “)
> - Then find this line -> %NVIDIA_DEV.0A35.06% = Section048, PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0A35&SUBSYS_1F171043
> - Press Enter, Paste this -> %NVIDIA_DEV.0A29.01% = Section050, PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0A29&SUBSYS_044F1028
> - Save the “nvam.inf” file
> - Re-run the NVidia setup again
> - Now you should be able to install driver already.
> - After restart, you will have the NVidia Control Panel icon on taskbar
> - You’re done

Comment: Unfortunately this method stopped working after (roughly) version 296. I've yet to find a decent solution for 3700/330M for driver versions after this revision. (Much to my woe)

Answer (score 0):

As of January 14, 2011, the latest version is 285.62. You can download it [directly from NVIDIA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/notebook-win7-winvista-64bit-285.62-whql-driver.html), and it should work. You may have selected the wrong GPU. Also as of when you posted this question, those drivers were VERY out of date (199.xx was long gone).

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late, but this is the solution to the problem. You don't have to edit any file, just install and it works. I think the trick is in using a switchable driver.

I can't remember where I downloaded it but it is the R289195 driver.

Answer (score 0):

The [NVIDIA 310.70WHQL](http://www.nvidia.com/object/notebook-win8-win7-winvista-310.70-whql-driver.html) worked for me on Windows 7 32-bit.

Straight forward download and install. Check under Device Manager: GT330 is displayed.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) button.